# Are aggregated objects forced to be an IUnknown reference?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, atl, midl

I am trying to implement shared logic using COM aggregation with ATL. I've defined a *base class*, called `CameraBase`, that is only available through aggregation. Therefor I've added the `aggregateable` annotation to it's `coclass`-declaration.

```
[
    uuid(...),
    aggregatable
]
coclass CameraBase
{
    [default] interface ICamera;
};
```

I've also added the `DECLARE_ONLY_AGGREGATEABLE` macro to the class definition.

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CCameraBase :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CCameraBase, &CLSID_CameraBase>,
    public ISupportErrorInfo,
    public IProvideClassInfoImpl<...>,
    public IDispatchImpl<...>
{
public:
    CCameraBase()
    {
    }

    DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_CAMERABASE)

    DECLARE_ONLY_AGGREGATABLE(CCameraBase)

    BEGIN_COM_MAP(CCameraBase)
        ...
    END_COM_MAP()

    DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

    ...
}
```

Now I have different classes who are using the logic of `CameraBase` somewhere. Therefor I've extented the com map of the parent class (e.g. `SampleCamera`):

```
BEGIN_COM_MAP(CSampleCamera)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_AGGREGATE(IID_ICamera, m_base)
    ...
END_COM_MAP

DECLARE_GET_CONTROLLING_UNKNOWN()
```

Since I want to be able to call the members on `CameraBase` (through the `ICamera` interface) from the parent class, I do not want to use `COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_AUTOAGGREGATE`, which stores the inner object's pointer as a reference of `IUnknown`. Therefor I am creating it on my own from the `FinalConstruct`-method:

```
HRESULT FinalConstruct()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    if (FAILED(hr = m_camera.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CameraBase, this->GetControllingUnknown(), CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER)))
        return hr;
}
```

Where `m_camera` is defined as `CComPtr<ICamera>`. However, this does result in a error `CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION` (HRESULT `0x80040110`). My current workaround is to store two references, `IUnknown` and `ICamera`, and query for the later one.

```
if (FAILED(hr = m_base.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CameraBase, this->GetControllingUnknown(), CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER)) ||
    FAILED(hr = m_base->QueryInterface(&m_camera)))
    return hr;
```

This works, but it feels kinda strange, since the class (`CameraBase`) that get's instanciated is the same in both cases. Am I missing something? Am I using the right way to aggregate the inner object? Why does the returned pointer of `CoCreateInstance` need to be of type `IUnknown`, if an outer unknown is passed?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An aggregatable COM object provides two distinct implementations of `IUnknown` - non-delegating and delegating.

The non-delegating implementation is the "normal" one - its `QueryInterface` hands out interfaces implemented by the aggregatable object, and its `AddRef` and `Release` control the lifetime of that object.

The delegating implementation, as the name suggests, delegates all three method calls to the controlling `IUnknown` of the outer object. All the other interfaces implemented by the object have their three `IUnknown` methods backed by this delegating implementation. This is how the aggregation can maintain an illusion for the client that it's dealing with a single COM object - it allows the client to query from an interface implemented by the outer to one implemented by the inner, and (more interestingly) vice versa. Recall that it's a requirement for `IUnknown` that `QueryInterface` implementation be symmetrical and transitive.

When `CoCreateInstance` is called with non-NULL controlling unknown parameter, it must request `IUnknown` from the inner object - that is the outer's one and only chance to obtain a non-delegating implementation. You cannot use any other interface pointer from the inner in the outer's interface map - again, all other interfaces are backed by a delegating unknown, so forwarding `QueryInterface` call to them would end up calling `QueryInterface` on the outer, and end up right back in the interface map, leading to an infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the detailled answer! :) 
So as far as I got it, I did nothing wrong and storing the non-delegating IUnknown pointer of the inner object is a requirement by COM's aggregation convention.